# Constructing a triangle with every vertex having its own color

Tags: opengl

```
    int COORDS_PER_VERTEX = 2;
    int vertexStride = COORDS_PER_VERTEX * 4;

    // Prepare the triangle coordinate data
    GLES20.glVertexAttribPointer(mPositionHandle, COORDS_PER_VERTEX,
                                 GLES20.GL_FLOAT, false,
                                 vertexStride, vertexBuffer);
    GLES20.glEnableVertexAttribArray(mPositionHandle);


    // Pass in the color information
    GLES20.glVertexAttribPointer(mColorHandle, COLOR_DATA_SIZE, GLES20.GL_FLOAT, false,
            colorStride, colorBuffer);

    GLES20.glEnableVertexAttribArray(mColorHandle);
```

I am trying to make every vertex of my triangle have its own color. I am using only x, y coordinates to represent a point. So a triangle can be represented as {1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0} for example.

My question is, what do I have to make the `colorStride` and the `COLOR_DATA_SIZE` variables to achieve this.

EDIT: My color and vertex array...

```
float[] colors = new float[] {1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f,
                              0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f,
                              0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f }
float[] tCoords= new float[] {0.0f, 0.0f
                              0.0f, 1.0f
                              1.0f, 1.0f }
```

EDIT2:

```
private void init() {
        vertexCount = triangleCoords.length/COORDS_PER_VERTEX;
        vertexStride = COORDS_PER_VERTEX * 4;
        // initialize vertex byte buffer for shape coordinates
        ByteBuffer bb = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(
                // (number of coordinate values * 4 bytes per float)
                triangleCoords.length * 4);
        // use the device hardware's native byte order
        bb.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());

        // create a floating point buffer from the ByteBuffer
        vertexBuffer = bb.asFloatBuffer();
        // add the coordinates to the FloatBuffer
        vertexBuffer.put(triangleCoords);
        // set the buffer to read the first coordinate
        vertexBuffer.position(0);

        // initialize vertex byte buffer for shape coordinates
        bb = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(
                // (number of coordinate values * 4 bytes per float)
                color.length * 4);
        // use the device hardware's native byte order
        bb.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());

        // create a floating point buffer from the ByteBuffer
        colorBuffer = bb.asFloatBuffer();
        // add the coordinates to the FloatBuffer
        colorBuffer.put(color);
        // set the buffer to read the first coordinate
        colorBuffer.position(0);

        int vertexShader = loadShader(GLES20.GL_VERTEX_SHADER, vertexShaderCode);
        int fragmentShader = loadShader(GLES20.GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER, fragmentShaderCode);

        mProgram = GLES20.glCreateProgram();             // create empty OpenGL ES Program
        GLES20.glAttachShader(mProgram, vertexShader);   // add the vertex shader to program
        GLES20.glAttachShader(mProgram, fragmentShader); // add the fragment shader to program
        GLES20.glLinkProgram(mProgram);                  // creates OpenGL ES program executables
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

`COLOR_DATA_SIZE` = colour components per vertex (3, or 4 of you want alpha)

`colorStride` = `sizeof(GLfloat) * COLOR_DATA_SIZE`

Or, you can leave stride as 0, which means data is tightly packed and there is no gaps in between.

Comment: Colours array does not affect shape. How is your arrays data filled?

Comment: What is `colorBuffer` and `vertexBuffer`? It should be either arrays themselves (where is positions array, by the way?) if no vertex buffer is bound, or byte offset within vertex buffer. If vertex buffer is bound, it have to be filled with data, and correctly bound at the moment of VertexAttribPointer usage.

Comment: colorBuffer and vertexBuffer are FloatBuffers. I just say `colorBuffer.put(colors)` and `vertexBuffer.put(tCoords)`

Comment: Please see my second edit to see how im doing it exactly

Comment: GL calls appears to be correct. I don't know what language it is, perhaps arrays don't live long enough, or ByteBuffer not supposed to be used in that way.